# Arnold on Inhomogeneous Linear Equations with Periodic Coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-explanation

In the proof of this theorem, Arnold says "The mapping is an inhomogeneous linear mapping (why?)". Why is it obvious that it is so? Why can we write $\phi(T) = \lambda\phi(0) + C$ where $\lambda$ is the multiplier of the homogeneous equation?

Why does the assertion of the theorem follow from the fact that $\lambda \ne 1 $? Does it imply both assertions that the solution is of period T and there is exactly one such solution? Why?

[image: Theorem]
[image: Proof]

Answer (score 1):

This follows from the solution formula for linear first order equations,
$$
(e^{-F(x)}y(x))'=e^{-F(x)}[y'(x)-f(x)y(x)]=e^{-F(x)}g(x)\\
\implies
e^{-F(x)}y(x)-e^{-F(0)}y(0)=\int_0^xe^{-F(s)}g(s)\,ds
\\
\implies
y(x)=e^{F(x)}\left(y(0)+\int_0^xe^{-F(s)}g(s)\,ds\right)
$$
where $F(x)=\int_0^xf(t)\,dt$. As you see, the coefficient is $\lambda=e^{F(T)}$ with exactly the described properties.

---

Obviously, for a periodic solution you would need $y(T)=y(0)$, which allows to compute that value as
$$
y(0)=\frac{\int_0^xe^{-F(s)}g(s)\,ds}{e^{-F(T)}-1}
$$
as long as $F(T)\ne 0$.

Comment: I think this what that Arnold is trying to show in the line ()=(0)+, he's trying to derive this formula but he writes "(why?)"

Comment: Arnol'd is an old school Russian mathematician. It is traditional among them to invite the reader to think for themselves and solve small and sometimes larger gaps. I'm sure that the solution formula was previously treated, the "why?" stands short for "exercise for the reader".

Comment: Doesn't satisfy me because the book hasn't made use of this formula before. It introduced this formula however,

$y = \int_{x_0}^{x} e^{\int_{\epsilon}^x f(\gamma)d\gamma}g(\epsilon)d\epsilon$

which is the solution for the inhomogeneous linear equation with initial condition $y(x_0) = 0$

Comment: Then the book assumes an intro level knowledge in differential equations. This solution formula is the first non-exotic example in such a course ("exotic" meaning the Bernoulli, Riccati, Clairaut etc. special examples). It can be assumed to be common knowledge.

Comment: But the formula you provided already assumes that the solution is periodic, which is what we are set out to prove, isn't it?

Comment: No, as I wrote, that is the general solution formula for linear first order equations. Assumptions on periodicity only enter when setting $x=T$.

Comment: I understand now, would you also know about the proof for exactly one as I asked in the question?

Comment: I'm thinking ... Assume that there are 2 solutions $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$. Then $\phi_1(0) = \phi_1(T)$ and $\phi_2(0) = \phi_2(T)$ but $\phi_1(0) = \phi_2(0)$ because they correspond to the same initial condition. Therefore the solution has to be unique as they coincide for all points.